# Add custom styles to the Raft theme

Tags: customization, css

It seems that in WP6.1+ and the raft theme it's become much harder to customize styles. The footer has custom wp tags ala "wp-social-link" but in trying to override list-style-type in order so it doesn't have the default bullet the footer breaks (with valid json), style.css doesn't override anything even with a high specificity.. is there some trick to the raft theme I'm missing where I can customize styles?

Original code in the footer:

```
<!-- wp:social-link {"url":"https://domain.com/","service":"twitter"} /-->
```

My attempts to specify a list style type of none

```
<!-- wp:social-link {"style":{"list-style-type":"none"}}, "url":"https://domain.com/","service":"twitter"} /-->


<!-- wp:social-link {"style":{"listStyleType":"none"}}, "url":"https://domain.com/","service":"twitter"} /-->
```

The above two result in the social-link disappearing when switching from code to visual

And in the Raft theme's style.css and end of assets/css/build/style.css (probably compiled but thought I'd try anyway)

```
footer nav li.wp-social-link { list-style:none !important; }
footer nav li.wp-social-link::marker { content: ""};
```

Comment: You'll need to check with the theme's support team. Third-party theme support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: CSS works the same everywhere. All that matters is the HTML structure and any existing CSS. Make sure your CSS rules reflect the actual HTML structure and that your rules are more specific than any existing rules. Nothing WordPress does changes this behaviour.

Comment: @JacobPeattie If WordPress doesn't render/build the css (as noted in the question with the styles I have in style.css and that build generated style.css) or strips it from the markup as with WP6+'s new theming then the styles can't be applied, unfortunately and thus not reflected on the generated output. There aren't any styles with more specificity and the structure is correct, thus my question. I'll see if I can maybe setup a demo somewhere with the same theme - could be a long week and I'm wrong about the structure/specificity but I doubt it.